# how to run iOS 4 application on iOS 3.1.3

Tags: ios4, ios3.0

I have an iPhone with iOS 3.1.3. I have developed an application with ios 4.2. Application runs well expect autoscrolling. when i click textview it scolls automatically to see text contents. when i install in my iphone it terminates when i click on text view. What can I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use api's that are only in 4.2 you can set you project iOS Deployment Target to 3.1 in the build settings of your project.